# Getting appmetrics to send data to (Eclips) IBM Health centre

Tags: node.js, eclipse

Decided to set up appmetrics to monitor my app, but got stuck on getting Eclipse Health centre to, and I can't find any instructions (that I can understand).

Got a mosquito MTQQ broker installed (localhost port 1883)

Set up the appmetric (as a config file)

```
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics')


module.exports = {
    crMonitor: function(){
        var monitoring = appmetrics.monitor();
        monitoring.on('mqtt', function(data){
            console.log("MTQQ event at " + data.time+ " type " +data.method + " topic: " + data.topic)
        })
        monitoring.enable('socketio');
        monitoring.enable('eventloop');
        monitoring.enable('http');
        /*monitoring.on('initialized', function (env) {
            env = monitoring.getEnvironment();
            for (var entry in env) {
                console.log(entry + ':' + env[entry]);
            };
        });*/
        return monitoring;
    }

}
```

And when I start the application I get the following three lines:

- [Mon Mar 14 15:20:13 2016] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.loader INFO: Node Application Metrics 1.0.7.201602110606 (Agent Core 3.0.6.201511030958)
- [Mon Mar 14 15:20:13 2016] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.mqtt INFO: Connecting to broker localhost:1883
- [Mon Mar 14 15:20:14 2016] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.mqtt INFO: Connected to broker localhost:1883

So they are talking. But now comes how to set up Health Centre. Tried without manual, no luck, can start it, but can't find any way to configure source.

I then found this
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/configuringagent.html

But I can't make heads or toes of what I am suppose to do. I tried setting the environment (launchctl setenv IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS "-Xhealthcenter:port=1883") but as far as I can tell, eclipse healthcenter does not even attempt to gather information via MTQQ.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you're trying to get AppMetrics to send data to the Eclipse HealthCenter client via MQTT.

First, a bit of definition - AppMetrics is doing the job of what we call an Agent - this monitors your code extracting useful information that it will then send somewhere for analysis. In your case, you have the AppMetrics Agent sending the data over MQTT, and the log output you show proves it's connected to your Mosquito broker, so you're half way there already!

Now you want the Eclipse Health Center Client to connect to the Mosquito broker, get the data, perform analysis and produce graphs so you can visualise what's happening with your program. This is where your problem lies, as the link you have and the options you're trying are about setting up the Java Health Center AGENT, not the Eclipse Client. The instructions for installing the Eclipse Health Center Client are at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/installingclient.html - this includes links to the Eclipse Marketplace to install from there, or to the repository to include if using Eclipse's Install New Software option from the Help menu.

There's a diagram that explains all this visually at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/introduction.html

Hope this helps!